# Как передать управление из одного модуля в другой?

Tags: c++

Приветствую.
Есть модули: *modul1.cpp, modul2.cpp, modul3.cpp*. Как реализовать такое:
В *modul1.cpp* мы передаем управление модулю *modul2.cpp*, в нем выполняются какие-то функции, затем передаем управление *modul3.cpp*, в нем тоже выполняются некие функции, а затем возвращаемся в *modul1.cpp* и выполняем еще-что то и собственно все.
Видимо нужны глобальные переменные на все модули... Предположим `int a` и `int b`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое реализовать. Нужно полностью примитивное решение.

Интересует именно как в одном модуле передать управление другому модулю и т.д.

Comment: Ну так пишете вызовы функций модулей и всё. О какой еще передаче управления может идти речь? Что-то вроде нескольких main()? Ну так это же абсурд, насколько мне известно.

Comment: Т.е. если мы делаем #include modul1.cpp и там автоматически вызывается будет всегда вызываться функция main?
Нужен этот бред чисто для сдачи лабы по Технологии Программирования

Comment: ни делайте `#include <name.cpp>`. Кроме того, это приведет не к вызову функции `main`, а к её множественному определению.

Comment: а как тогда сделать чтобы при #include <name.cpp> автоматически вызывалась например функция fciya() из этого файла?
Или не при include
В общем, чтобы мы кидали в месте программы адрес модуля, и из него вызывалась функция
Такой бред нам просто задали, вот текст задания


Запускающий модуль modul_m.c принимает с клавиатуры значения границ отрезка  [a, b] и записывает их в файл prognoz.dat, после чего вызывает модуль modul_2.c, содержащий функцию tablpr_2.

Comment: Посмотрите на мой ответ. Там все расписано. Фразу 
>> после чего вызывает модуль modul_2.c, содержащий функцию tablpr_2.

следует читать так: "вызывает с modul_2.c функцию tablpr_2".

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а где то так

```
//module1
#include "module2.h"

void own_funcs() {
  // soma code
}

int main()
{
  m2_funcs(); // передали управление в второй модуль
  own_funcs();
}

// module2
#include "module3.h"

void m2_f1() {
}

void m2_f2() {
}

m2_funcs()
{
  // вначале какой то код
  m2_f1();
  m2_f2();
  m3_funcs(); // передали управление в модуль три
}

// module3
m3_funcs()
{
  // some code
}
```

Я объявил их всех как void, но никто не мешает Вам объявить их по другому и функции могут возвратить какое то значение, а также получать параметры. Может и глобальных переменных не нужно будет.

> > Интересует именно как в одном модуле передать управление другому модулю...и т.д.

А просто  - вызвать функцию с другого "модуля" (в данном случае под модулем Вы понимаете файл). Как только вызванная функция завершится, она автоматически передаст управление в вызываемый модуль.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильно ли я тебя понял. Тебе нужно, чтобы каждый cpp-файл сам выполнял какой-то код без вызова функций из другого файла? Если да, то это делается так:

```
//Module1.cpp
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello from Module1.cpp!\n";
    return 0;
}

//Module2.cpp
int module2_main()
{
    cout << "Hello from Module2.cpp!\n";
    return 0;
}
int module2_call=module_main();

//Module3.cpp
int module3_main()
{
    cout << "Hello from Module3.cpp!\n";
    return 0;
}
int module3_call=module3_main();
```

cpp-файлы надо подключать не через include, а через командную строку компилятора. В IDE обычно их надо просто добавить в папку "Файлы исходного кода" ("Source files").

P. S. Ещё раз перечитал вопрос. Оказывается, я и в самом деле неправильно тебя понял. Меня сбили с толку комментарии, в которых ты говорил про что-то другое. Другой ответ правильный.